# Unity Theming Transparent Panel

Tags: unity, themes, panel, css, theme-development

I am making a theme for Ubuntu and just want to know 2 things (at the moment):

1. How can I set the transparency of the panel from the theme
   and
2. How can I set the height of the panel from within the theme's css file?

Comment: Maybe you can get some hint from here .  http://askubuntu.com/questions/53321/how-does-one-retheme-the-unity-panel-with-gtk?rq=1